# Having issues with Google Sheets formula combing ArrayFormula with IF

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, array-formulas

This works the way I want it to but I want to use the ArrayFormula to add the formula to the whole column starting at Cell J2:

```
=IF(E2:E="Closed","",MINUS(TODAY(),I2))
```

This doesn't work:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(E2:E="Closed","",,J2:J), MINUS(TODAY(),I2))
```

I have tried multiple ways to add the ArrayFormula into it and reorganized it multiple ways but it failed.

Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Please use the following formula

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(I2:I<>"", IF(E2:E="Closed","CL",MINUS(TODAY(),I2:I)),""))
```

*(where today is May 20th. Adjust ranges and notifications to your liking)*

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort to help me resolve this. I tried the formula replacing I with J but then I get the follwing error: "Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in J3." This is the formula I used: =ArrayFormula(IF(J2:J<>"", IF(E2:E="Closed",MINUS(TODAY(),I2:I)),""))

Comment: You get that error because there is content/values in cell `J3`. For any array to work you have to keep all cells they will occupy empty.